# Assign first character of a char array to another variable

Tags: c, arrays, char, element

I would like to grab a single character from a char array and move it into another character array. It is driving me crazy that i am having so much difficulties with something so simple.

My code is meant to reverse a string 2 values at a time. I have a string (ABCDEFGH) and i want to separate it into two strings (ACEG & BDFH). How would i go about doing this?

Currently, i have this:

```
char *hexrev(char str[]){

    int i = 0;
    char a[256];
    char b[256];
    int len = strlen(str);

    for(i; i<len-1; i+=2)
    {
        printf("str[i] : %c\n", str[i]);
        a[0] = str[i];
        b[0] = str[i+1];
        a[1] = '\0';
        b[1] = '\0';
        printf("A : %s\n", a);
        printf("B : %s\n", b);
    }
    return str;
}
```

By changing sizeof(str) to strlen(str) and terminating a & b, I was able to get the code to work. Thank you!

Comment: `str` is a pointer. Are you sure you want to use it's size in the loop condition?

Comment: `a[0]`, `b[0]` increment index. `int j=0;... a[j++] = str[i];` then `a[j] = '\0';`

Comment: @12nm What is the sense of this function? In fact it does nothing.

Comment: What does "reverse a string 2 values at a time" even mean?

Comment: the function is just beta for a function that takes a hex value i.e 4D FE 4E B2 and changes it to look like B2 4E FE 4D

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `sizeof` on an array inside a function. You must either use `strlen()` (once, preferrably) to compute the length, or pass it in as an extra argument.

Also you cannot legally print `a` and `b` as strings since you never ensure they're properly terminated.

Third, you only ever write to the first characters of `a` and `b`, so they will never grow longer than 1 character.

You should show a slightly more complete example, at least including the code that does the call to your function.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
char a[256];
char b[256];
int len = strlen(str);

for(i; i<len-1; i+=2){
    a[j]   = str[i];
    b[j++] = str[i+1];
}
a[j] = b[j] = '\0';
printf("A : %s\n", a);
printf("B : %s\n", b);
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char str[] = "ABCDEFGHI";//In the case of odd-length
    char a[256]={0};//letter of the index of odd numbered.(odd : 1 origin)
    char b[256]={0};//for even
    int i;
    char *p[] = {a, b};

    for(i = 0; str[i]; ++i){
        *p[i & 1]++ = str[i];
    }
    printf("A : %s\n", a);//ACEGI
    printf("B : %s\n", b);//BDFH
    return 0;
}
```